# Euler's equation for an incompressible fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am trying to solve the following problem:

[image]

I rearranged the Euler equation to find grad(p) and then I did 
-u.grad(p) to see if i could simplify this to get the LHS

However i am very stuck on what happens when i apply -u.grad(p)
i would appreciate any hints to help me

Comment: multiply the first equation by $u$ and use hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$\frac{D\phi}{Dt}=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}+\vec{u}.\nabla \phi$

$=\vec{u}.\nabla \phi$ since $ \phi$ is

time independent.